# EF 5 - Get Migrations Scaffold to live in a seperate project

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I don't particularly want the Entity Framework migrations scaffold code in my Data Access project.  I've got a Console app that I manage database scripts with - so I'd like it live in here:

Project.DataAccess
Project.DatabaseManagement -this is my Console App

So far I'm here ...

```
enable-migrations -ProjectName Project.DataAccess -StartUpProjectName Project.DatabaseManagement
```

The above works - but the scaffold code goes in the DataAccess project ...

But if I don't give -ProjectName as Project.DataAccess it complains that it can't find my Context file.

Can anyone assist please?

Comment: have your tried to add a reference to the DAL an EF in console APP and  move the generated code to the Console APP.  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this is possible. The migrations are conceptually related to and coupled with the entity framework data access portion of your project.

By entering the project name, you are telling the migration engine which entity framework library to create a migration for.

See here for more information.
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/398982

**EDIT:**
Found a solution, but it requires using a (free) third party migrations tool:
https://github.com/migratordotnet/Migrator.NET/wiki/Getting-Started

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks for the info - I'm just going to accept that the migrations will have to live with my data access.